# AWS Lambda - read csv and convert to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, aws-lambda

I have got a simple Lambda code to read the csv file from S3 Bucket. All is working fine however I tried to get the csv data to pandas data frame and the error comes up `string indices must be integers`

My code is bog-standard but I just need to use the csv as a data frame for further manipulation. The hashed line is the source of the error. I can print data with no problems so the bucket and file details are configured properly.

**updated code**

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import glob
import time
import os
from datetime import datetime
from csv import reader
import boto3
import traceback
import io

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
            
        bucket_name = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
        s3_file_name = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["object"]["key"]
        resp = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=s3_file_name)
        
        data = resp['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
        df=pd.DataFrame( list(reader(data)))
        print (df.head())

    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        

        
        
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello fr2om Lambda!')
    }
    
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: Please include the traceback message so that we can easily spot the errant line.

Comment: Did you try `pd.read_csv(data)`?

Comment: When you have something like `event["Records"][0]["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]` giving you a problem, you can toss in some thow away code to narrow it down. `event["Records"]` followed by `event["Records"][0]["s3"]` and ``event["Records"][0]["s3"]["bucket"]`. Whichever one blows up will let you know the problem.

Comment: You could `import traceback` and in your exception handler add `traceback.print_exc()`.

Comment: @tdelaney. Just added updated code. When I run it it gives me the following results: `Response:
(..) - cut it short
Function logs:
START RequestId: d99891e1-6c63-4307-acb5-f94bcb92217c Version: $LATEST
                  0
0  ResponseMetadata
1      AcceptRanges
2      LastModified
3     ContentLength
4              ETag
END RequestId: d99891e1-6c63-4307-acb5-f94bcb92217c
REPORT RequestId: d99891e1-6c63-4307-acb5-f94bcb92217c Duration: 463.01 ms Billed Duration: 500 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 128 MB Init Duration: 1382.89 ms`

Comment: so the code works now but it produces the wrong data inside the data frame.

Comment: You say the code works now, but that it doesn't work? What exactly is the issue and what is the expected result, can you clarify please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that your problem is likely tied to this line - *df=pd.DataFrame( list(reader(data)))* in your function.  The answer below should allow you to read the csv file into the pandas dataframe for processes.

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   try:
       bucket_name = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
       s3_file_name = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["object"]["key"]
       resp = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=s3_file_name)

       ###########################################
       # one of these methods should work for you. 
       # Method 1
       # df_s3_data = pd.read_csv(resp['Body'], sep=',')
       #
       # Method 2
       # df_s3_data = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(resp['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')))
       ###########################################
       print(df_s3_data.head())

   except Exception as err:
      print(err)
```

Comment: Nope. It gives me `No columns to parse from file`

Comment: @Kalenji Did you try the second df_s3_data that is commented out?

Comment: Method 1 worked! One additional question, did you manage to get files from S3 to lambda based on the part of the file name?

Answer (score 4):

```py
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import glob
import time
import os
from datetime import datetime
from csv import reader
import boto3
import io

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
            
        bucket_name = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
        s3_file_name = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["object"]["key"]
        obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key= s3_file_name)
        df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body']) # 'Body' is a key word
        print(df.head())

    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello fr2om Lambda!')
    }
```

Comment: This answer worked for me. The additional .read() method performed in the accepted answer was giving me errors

Answer (score 1):

You can read the S3 file directly from pandas using read_csv:

```py
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:            
        bucket_name = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
        s3_file_name = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["object"]["key"]

        # This 'magic' needs s3fs (https://pypi.org/project/s3fs/)
        df=pd.read_csv(f's3://{bucket_name}/{s3_file_name}', sep=',')

        print (df.head())

    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
```

#### Things to remember:

- Pandas needs [s3fs](https://pypi.org/project/s3fs/) to read remote files - see [Reading Remote Files] in pandas documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#reading-remote-files)
- You'll need to package the s3fs library with your lambda - see [AWS Lambda deployment package in Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html)
- If you're using this outside a lambda (for thesting) the tricky part is authentication.
- Since you're billed for CPU and Memory usage, Pandas [DataFrame.info()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html) might help you to assess CSV memory usage and/or troubleshoot out-of-memory errors:

```py
   # Track memory usage at cost of CPU. Great for troubleshooting. Use wisely.
   print(df.info(verbose=True, memory_usage='deep'))
```